# OOP - When to Use Properties vs When to Use Return Values

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I am designing a process that should be run daily at work, and I've written a class to do the work. It looks something like this:

```
class LeadReport {

    public $posts               = array();
    public $fields              = array();

    protected _getPost() {
        // get posts of a certain type
        // set them to the property $this->posts
    }

    protected _getFields() {
        // use $this->posts to get fields
        // set $this->fields
    }

    protected _writeCsv() {
       // use the properties to write a csv
    }

    protected _sendMail() {
       // attach a csv and send it
    }
    public function main() {
        $this->out('Lead Report');
        $this->out("Getting Yesterday's Posts...");
        $this->_getPosts();
        $this->out("Done.");
        $this->out("Next, Parsing the Fields...");
        $this->_getFields();
        $this->out("Done.");
        $this->out("Next, Writing the CSVs...");
        $this->_writeCsv();
        $this->out("Done.");
        $this->out("Finally, Sending Mail");
        $this->_sendMail();
        $this->out('Bye!');
    }
}
```

After showing this code to one of my colleagues, he commented that the _get() methods should have return values, and that the _write() and _sendMail() methods should use those values as parameters.

So, two questions:
1) Which is "correct" in this case (properties or return values)?
2) Is there a general rule or principle that governs when to use properties over when to use return values in object oriented programming?

Comment: I think your colleague is getting at the separation of concerns and testability.  In this code, if something doesn't work, you'll have little idea where the error happened.  You'd probably want to create a class that just transforms the posts into a class with exposed fields, and another that takes that result class and creates a file, and a third that sends the file. etc. Each of these can be tested individually, and it also it frees your file creating and email sending classes to work with more than one narrow set of data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This suggestion makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe the source of your question comes from the fact that you are not entirely convinced that using properties is better than having public fields. For example here, common practice says that should not have `posts` and `fields` as public. You should use the `getField` method or a `Field` protected property to regulate access to those fields. Having a protected `getField` and a public `fields` doesn't really make sense.

In this case your colleague may be pointing at two things. The fact that you need to use Properties and not public fields and also the fact that it is probably better to pass the post into the method and not have the method access a property if you can. That way you don't have to set a property before calling the method. Think of it as a way of documenting what the method needs for it to operate. In this way another developer doesn't need to know which properties need to be set for the method to work. Everything the method needs should be passed in.

Regarding why we need properties in the first place? why shouldn't you use public fields. Isn't it more convenient? It sure is. The reason we use properties and not public fields is that just like most other concepts in OOP, you want your object to hide its details from the outside world and just project well defined interfaces of its state. Why? Ultimately to hide implementation details and keep internal change to ripple out(Encapsulation). Also, accessing properties has the added benefit of debugging. You can simply set a breakpoint in a property to see when a variable is changed or simply do a check if the variable is of certain value. Instead of littering your code with said check all over the place. There are many more goodies that come with this, returning readonly values, access control, etc.

To sum up, fields are though of as internal state. Properties(actual get/set methods) are though of as methods that interact with internal state. Having an outside object interact with interfaces is smiley face. Having outside class interact with internal state directly is frowny face.